# divs fall outside div borders when more than 2 are present

Tags: html, css

I have a page where users can post text (a simple title and content), and other users can comment on those posts. However, after more than 2 comments are made, they fall outside the parent post's borders, further and further down until hitting the `body`

The code below is the rendered HTML from my php file.

```css
#content {
  margin: 20px;
}

#postcontent {
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgb(192, 192, 192);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#postcontent:focus {
  border: 1px solid #5865F2;
}

#entirepost {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  /* border-radius: 5px; */
  padding: 20px;
}

#commentstextarea {
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#commentstextarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #5865F2;
}

#comments {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#commentcontent {
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
}

#commentstitle {
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

#title {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgb(192, 192, 192);
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#title:focus {
  border: 1px solid #5865F2;
}

#dropdownmenu i {
  float: right;
}

#dropdownmenu {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" style="margin-top:100px">
  <h1 class="display-4">Discussion Board</h1>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
New Post <b style="font-size:large">+</b>
</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">New Post</h4>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="post">
            <input name="post_title" type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title...">
            <textarea name="post_content" rows="5" placeholder="Write something..." id="postcontent" pattern="[^()/><\][\\\x22,;|]+" required=""></textarea>
            <button name="post" id="postbtn" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Post</button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
        <p style="text-align: right;margin-right:15px;">Discussion Board</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="entirepost">
    <div id="posts">
      <a style="float:right; font-size: large;" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="deletepost.php?id=35"><b>×</b></a>
      <h3>hi</h3>
      <p>
        hg\r\n
      </p>
      <small> 
        <i> 
            Daniel R                
        </i>
        <span class="badge bg-primary">Developer</span> ·
            A few seconds ago                
    </small>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="comments">
      <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="35">
        <textarea name="comment_content" rows="2" cols="64" id="commentstextarea" placeholder="Comment..." required=""></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="comment" value="Comment" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
      </form>
      <div id="commentcontent">
        adsf<br>
        <small>
            <i>Daniel R</i>
            <span class="badge bg-primary">Developer</span> ·
            A few seconds ago                    
        </small>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="commentcontent">
      df<br>
      <small>
            <i>Daniel R</i>
            <span class="badge bg-primary">Developer</span> ·
            A few seconds ago                   
            </small>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="commentcontent">
    afd<br>
    <small>
            <i>Daniel R</i>
            <span class="badge bg-primary">Developer</span> ·
            A few seconds ago                    
        </small>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screeenshot of my issue]
[image: Inspected screenshot of my issue]

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP please

Comment: @j08961 Sorry! Fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each commentcontent there is one closing `</div>` too much.
So after the first commentcontent the parent comment div is closed (too soon). After the second commentcontent the parent modal div gets closed (too soon). After the third ...

So that probably means that your php script generates one `</div>` too much for each commentcontent.

BTW commentcontent should probably be a class instead of an id.

Comment: Agh! I knew it would be something tiny like that. Happens to the best of us, thank you!